# Joomla 1.5 - JTable queries always doing UPDATE instead of INSERT

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

The following code is straight from the docs and should insert a row into the "test" table.

```
$row = &JTable::getInstance('test', 'Table');
if (!$row->bind( array('user_id'=>123, 'customer_id'=>1234) )) {
    return JError::raiseWarning( 500, $row->getError() );
}
if (!$row->store()) {
    JError::raiseError(500, $row->getError() );
}
```

My table class looks like this:

```
class TableTest extends JTable
{
    var $user_id = null;
    var $customer_id = null;

    function __construct(&$db)
    {
        parent::__construct( '#__ipwatch', 'user_id', $db );
    }   

}
```

`SELECT` queries work fine, but not `INSERT` ones. Through debugging I find that the query being executed is `UPDATE jos_test SET customer_id='1234' WHERE user_id='123'`, which fails because the row doesn't exist yet in the database (should `INSERT` instead of `UPDATE`).

---

While digging through the Joomla code I find this:

```
function __construct( $table, $key, &$db )
{
    $this->_tbl     = $table;
    $this->_tbl_key = $key;
    $this->_db      =& $db;
}

    .....
    .....

function store( $updateNulls=false )
{
    $k = $this->_tbl_key;

    if( $this->$k)
    {
        $ret = $this->_db->updateObject( $this->_tbl, $this, $this->_tbl_key, $updateNulls );
    }
    else
    {
        $ret = $this->_db->insertObject( $this->_tbl, $this, $this->_tbl_key );
    }
    if( !$ret )
    {
        $this->setError(get_class( $this ).'::store failed - '.$this->_db->getErrorMsg());
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

`_tbl_key` here is "user_id" that I passed in my TableTest class, so it would appear that it will always call updateObject() when this key is set. Which is baffling.

Anyone have any insight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function store( $updateNulls=false )
{
    // You set user_id so this branch is executed
    if( $this->$k)
    {
        $ret = $this->_db->updateObject( $this->_tbl, $this, $this->_tbl_key, $updateNulls );
    }
    // ...
```

Looking at the code it seems to me that store() check if the primary key field is present and if it use updateObject(). This means if you want to store a new user you can't specify the user_id.

Comment: Ah yes, the issue was that I'm not using an auto-incrementing primary key (as my table associates existing user ID with customer ID), so passing user_id caused an UPDATE query. Since I need to specify my primary key value, I hacked a workaround by calling `insertObject` directly

Comment: ^^^ And this workaround broke in Joomla 2.5, so I succumbed and used a primary key with the table.